# How to use Xcode7 instruments leaks tool located the code where leaks occurred

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode7, instruments

I followed the apple official instruction ,but I can't find the head icon described in instruction.And I got this [leak  information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4p3r.jpg),So I click the information [The code when I Click the information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3eUG.jpg)

I have reviewed my code , could't find any possible occurred leak by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Please pull the information from Apple alone , they have the step by step process 
    what are the leaks problem oocur?
    where it occur?
    what is the solution to prevent from zombie error? memory leakage?
   Please follow the below apple link from my suggestion?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingMemoryLeaksinYourApp/FindingMemoryLeaksinYourApp.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH81-SW1

Comment: Some leaks that use instruments can't located the code according to the instruments guide . But the static analyze solved part of my problem .Thanks anyway~

Comment: In another way you can see the memory leakage through cmd+shift+B